# Bind root data in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

vue structure:

```
<Root>
  <App>
   <component>
```

function in main.js:

```
function() {
            axios.get('/app-api/call').then(function (resp, error) {
                _this.response = resp.data;
            })
        }
```

and i try to assign to variable in child component like:

```
this.variable.value = this.$root.response
```

but response of server is later then child component created, how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Have you implemented vuex? You can dispatch actions which can be API calls and access state from all routes.

Answer (score 0):

In the main.js, please try it.

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  async mounted() {
    let response = await axios.get('/app-api/call')
    _this.response = response.data
  }
}).$mount("#app")
```